Does opening files in shared mode have a performance hit?
I am writing a small utility based on memory mapped files, which can be used on both posix systems (Linux etc...) and Windows.
In contrast to posix systems, on Windows files are opened by default with exclusive access (i.e. no other process can access the file).
Since I prefer having the same behavior of the utility whatever the OS, I am currently opening the files with shared access on Windows (FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE flags in CreateFileA(): is there some performance penalty doing so? If yes, is it significant? The utility is made to manipulate potentially huge data volumes, so I/O performances are something I care about here...
What I am thinking about for instance, if a file is opened with shared access, for each I/O the kernel may have to check if the file is opened elsewhere to ensure consistency, which can give some overheads. But I don't know how it really works.
PS: I know, I could test by myself, but actually no: I want to support Windows, but I am primarily developing on and for posix. On Windows I am just testing the correctness of the code, using the MSYS2 environment: this environment has apparently significant overheads, particularly when accessing the filesystem, so measuring the performances is pointless.

no default shared mode. you always need direct set it in api. and no any performance penalty only because you open file in some shared mode

Use GlobalMemoryStatus to see virtual memory space of the process, physical memory, and the size of the page file. You'll find that there's no performance penalty.

@Torrecto-MSFT How does it show the absence of performance penalty? I can imagine that in the case of concurrent access to a file (shared mode) the kernel has more work to do, to check the different states, which can result in some overheads. But I don't really now.

@PierU You only need to compare the data before and after creating and opening the file to confirm that there is no performance penalty.https://i.sstatic.net/5D2Xa.png

@Torrecto-MSFT Sorry, but I still can't how this relates to the performance

@PierU Memory Just the part of Performance Counters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/PerfCtrs/performance-counters-portal Or you want is collecting data of CPU usage?
